# SQL: Retrieve all meetings from year 2005 and after

Tags: sql

Let's say I have 2 tables (with many more rows, that's just an example):

Meetings

| ID | Topic | Leader |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Business | Mark |
| A | Business | Mark |
| B | Planning | John |

Calendar

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2005 |
| A | 2006 |
| B | 2004 |

And I want to get all the IDs, topics and leaders for the meetings with ID A that happened in or after year 2005. Will something like this work?

```
SELECT ID, Topic, Leader
FROM Meetings m, Calendar c
WHERE ID = 'A' AND Year >= 2005
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the tables together.  I presume you want:

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Topic, m.Leader
FROM Meetings m JOIN
     Calendar c
     ON m.id = c.id
WHERE m.ID = 'A' AND c.Year >= 2005;
```

In addition to the `JOIN`, note the use of table aliases and qualified column names.  This is very important because in your query `id` is ambiguous and would result in an ambiguous column error (even using a `JOIN`).

Answer (score -1):

Another way without explicit JOIN operator is

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Topic, m.Leader
FROM Meetings m, Calendar c
WHERE ID = 'A' AND Year >= 2005
AND m.ID = c.ID
```

Comment: I would not be suggesting the old-style pre-sql92 syntax to anyone